# Chart.js: how to disable all effects?

Tags: chart.js

We have a quite long chart with around 10 lines, each consisting of approx 4000 values. Hovering and tooltip works great. However, when clicking on legend items the curves move in and out ... both is sluggish because of fading and moving lines. How can I disable all such effects to improve speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to disable animations and interactions to improve the speed and remove the fading and moving lines when clicking on legend items.

##### Disable Animations:

```
options: {
    animation: false, // Disable all animations
   }
```

##### Disable Interactions:

```
options: {
    hover: {
      mode: null, // Disable hovering interactions
    },
    interaction: {
      mode: 'index', // Disable tooltip interactions
    }
```